# Android listview save hidden text

Tags: android, json, listview, android-arrayadapter

I wrote simple app to fetch data from server and show into the listView, when I fetch the data from server with json my data is:

```
id:2,offer:welcome to my shop
```

I would like to show `offer` into the listView and `id` hidden the listview row, And when I click the listView row. Show into Toast:

```
id=2
```

ListView adaptor is:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> myAdaptor = new ArrayAdapter<String>(travelactivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, itemsList);
                    mylist.setAdapter(myAdaptor);
```

How can I solve that? 
my code is:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.travelcountrylist);
        new HttpAsyncTask().execute("http://yyyy.org/tcountry.aspx");
         listview.setOnitemClick(){
               //start other activity and send id value to activity

         }

    }
    ///this is HttpAsyncTask method
    HttpAsyncTask(){
               Fill the listview data
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep a different array to save id.

```
 ArrayList<String> ids=new ArrayList<String>();
// after reading jsonarray
```

ids.add(jobj.getString("id");

```
    grid.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    Toast.makeText(context,"clicked"+ids(position),1500).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });



   }
```

Comment: thanks,ِDo after click the item in the listview and send the id to  activity2 and when press back button on activity2 and return to the this ativity ArrayList not null?

Comment: declare the arraylist as public static in a class named Constantss.java and use it inside your activitites so that the data will be there even if you move front or back.You can also use intent.putExtras to pass data between two activities.

Comment: thanks for pay attention to my problem,my friend!,how can i declare arraylist into the activity public,becuase my json read part into the one method for example readJSON() and when read the json and fill into the arrayList my listview click event into the activity onCreate method.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this solution will help you as you need . But try this.

- Create a Custom adapter with both values id and offer and context of the activity
- In the adapter use on click of the listview row show a toast.

Like

```
    listRowLayout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                yourListActivity.showToast(id);
        }
 });
```